# Best way to implement plugin support

Tags: c++, c, plugins, external

i have a software in c++ MFC that have some public interface for plugin using C exports.

I´m about to open the software for external 3 party development. 
But using a C export are for hardcore programmers.

What the best way to implement it ? I heard about LUA, but want to know about other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

I think this really depends on the type of program and your target audience. WoW sure wouldn't have as many addons as it does had it required C and a compiler to write them. But I sure wouldn't want to write a large addon in Lua.

So, before anything else you need to decide whether you want to use a scripting language or a compiled language. If you target casual users then a scripting language might be a better choice. If you target professional developers (say, a financial package whose addons are developed by in-house programmers) then compiled language might work best.

Oh, and also - why don't you ask a bunch of potential plugin developers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but the software will be released to mainstream as a free software. So i dont have potential plugin developers yet, but i want to keep the things easy as possible to attract they.

Comment: @bratao if you don't have any developers _yet_, and the C interface is already done, then I would say release first, and then see how much demand there is for any other plugin environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C export programming examples that work for you I suggest you put your pre-conceived "hardcore" notions aside and as Nike says "just do it."

It may well be easier than you expected.

Comment: But i should "attract" the Developers to the project. And for Sure C Export are not for the nowdays developers.

Answer (score 0):

We use a c-naming convention and the `dlopen\LoadLibrary` family of functions to load a plugin (.dll or .so), find the 3 needed methods (`create_plugin()`, `destroy_plugin()`, and `get_type()`.

A plugin implementer merely has to make sure that the equivalent (in whatever language they use) is visibile in the library

```
extern "C" PLUGIN_API plugin_interface* create_plugin( arg_pack* );
extern "C" PLUGIN_API void destroy_plugin( plugin_interface* );
extern "C" PLUGIN_API const char* get_type();
```

Depending on what you need your plugin to do, arg_pack can be replaced with specific arguments.

Check out the documentation for `[gmodule][1]` to see a cross-platform library to do this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Want to attract folks? JavaScript is hot. Embed the v8 engine.

http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html

Answer (score 0):

Implement a binary interface using exported C functions to create and return interfaces.

```
// your_plugin_header

// Plugins must implement this interface
struct PluginInterface {
  virtual void Release()=0;
  virtual void Method()=0;
  virtual void Method2()=0;
};


// Plugin dll's must export this function that creates a new object that implements
// the PluginInterface;
extern "C" bool CreatePluginObject(PluginInterface**);
```

Then, implement an example plugin as a Lua / Javascript / Python bridge, and bundle that with your software. Out the box you support both a tightly coupled C++ interface, PLUS a highly scriptable plugin interface, AND, if anyone prefers a different script, they can do it themselves.